# JSFiddle how do I add URLs for server sided script to my MySQL server?

Tags: javascript

I am getting to know JFiddle and it looks fantastic. Question though is: I have JS I want to put into JSFiddle but it uses data fed to it by executing a server sided script and reading returning JSON. Is this possible to execute? I cannot get it working in my example here: `[http://jsfiddle.net/nNt7R/2/]`

I should add the call to the server sided script is part of d3.JSON. Thanks!

Comment: Try creating a standalone JSON file and copy-pasting it as a new file in [Plunker](plnkr.co) and loading that file using `d3.json`. Accessing files on a different domain using Javascript requires either `JSONP`, or else CORS.

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle has an area on the left called <kbd>External Resources</kbd>. You can use this to include links to JavaScript and CSS that aren't part of the JSFiddle bundle (i.e. jQuery, etc).

In this case, you'd need to have a JS script that calls your server side script and returns a value. You can then add a link to this script and reference it in your jsFiddles

Answer (score 0):

You have to use absolute URIs (or scheme relative URLs) if you want to reference resources on another server.

i.e. You can't start with `www.something` or `/`, you must use `http://www.something`, `https://www.something` or `//www.something`.

You must also [give JSFiddle permission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) to tell browsers to access resources on your server, or otherwise [circumvent the same origin policy](/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)